# Is SFTP without keys still better than FTP?

Tags: ssh, security, ftp, sftp

I have a question regarding SFTP and security.
Is using SFTP without keys, **still** more secure (eg. encrypted) than plain FTP?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's still encrypted and therefore much more secure. Just make sure to use a strong password, and it's best to use a non-standard port or you'll have bots constantly hitting your server trying to guess the password.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Private/public key authentication just generally make the encryption stronger as the keys are usually way longer (1024-2048 bits) and a way more random than a typical password.

Also with keys you can:

- Use SSH authentication agent to allow automatic, yet reasonable secure, authentication, without need to type password every time (as opposite to insecure storing of password in some profile)
- Use SSH agent forwarding to automatically authenticate session opened within already authenticated session (SSH tunnel)
- You can have multiple keys for a single account, each with different privileges (well that's implementation specific, you can theoretically have the same with passwords, but I haven't seen server that would allow this).

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

With SFTP traffic is encrypted, so in that sense it is more secure than plain FTP.

On the other hand, SFTP is just a subsystem of SSH. You have to configure SSH carefully in order to restrict people accessing the server to a chroot environment and disallow shell and SCP access. That's usually granted by default for most FTP servers.